# .htaccess url rewrite remove 2 id

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex

Is it possible to delete 2 parameters ID of the url & just show the number. Currently i have url like this:

```
http://localhost/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html?prometheus_id=10082&id=73
```

Needed URL:

```
http://localhost/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html/10082&73
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1.php
RewriteRule ^product_configurator.php/(\d+)$ product_configurator.php?prometheus_id=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you already rewriting the URL to change the URL extension from `.html` to `.php`? (Are you doing this for many different URLs?) So, the "actual" URL/filename is really `product_configurator.php`? And please clarify where your `.htaccess` file is located? By the look of your directives, it is inside the `/photo_gallery/public/` subdirectory?

Comment: @ MrWhite Thank you for your answer .1. I'm changing php to html. Are you doing this for many different URLs? - for all file with php 2. product_configurator.php - yes, it's file. 3. located - public, in the folder photo_gallery - there is nothing, no file, only subfolders public and private.

Comment: @ MrWhite This work's for me RewriteRule ^show.php/(\d+)$ show.php?id=$1 [NC,L] but only one id http://localhost/photo_gallery/public/show.html/73

Comment: @ MrWhite I don't know how to remove 2 id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, (looking at your directives) that your `.htaccess` file is located at `/photo_gallery/public/.htaccess`.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^product_configurator.php/(\d+)$ product_configurator.php?prometheus_id=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
> ```

This is close, although you only have a single capturing subpattern (ie. `(\d+)`), yet you have two backreferences (ie. `$1` and `$2`) in the *substitution* string. You are also only matching digits (`\d`), whereas the pattern you are wanting to match contains `&` - a non-digit. So the above will simply fail to match.

You have also introduced a `.php` extension, whereas the example URLs you posted consist of `.html`. I'm assuming you are already rewriting `.html` to `.php` (as suggested by your directives). However, you should do this directly with a single directive.

Your rewrite to change the extension from `.html` to `.php` (ie. `RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1.php`) would also overwrite the information you are trying to match since this is included in the URL-path.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "product_configurator.html/10082&73"
RewriteRule ^(product_configurator)\.html/(\d+)&(\d+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

We capture the `product_configurator` string from the request (into the `$1` backreference) to save repetition in the *substitution* string. `$2` and `$3` then represent the values before and after the `&` in the URL-path.

I've removed the `NC` flag to prevent a potential "duplicate content" issue. Unless you specifically need a case-insensitive match, the `NC` flag should be avoided.

And then...

```
# Rewrite other ".html" requests to ".php"
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.